# Using symmetric key(tls-psk) to configure SSL on Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, tls-psk

I have already successfully used asymmetric keys and certificate to configure SSL on jetty by following [this website](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL#Configuring_Jetty_for_SSL).

Now, I want to used symmetric key to configure SSL on jetty.

I used keytool to generate the symmetric key by following command:

```
keytool -genseckey -alias mykey -keyalg AES -keysize 256 -storetype jceks -keystore mykeystore
```

Then, I configure the keystore and its password on jetty.

```
org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.https.enabled=true
org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.https.port=8443
org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.ssl.password=password
org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.ssl.keypassword= password
org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.ssl.keystore=/Users/user/key/mykeystore 
org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2
```

When I use Chrome to connect to the website, the website shows:

### ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Does Jetty support this way by using symmetric key(tls-psk) to configure SSL?

Comment: Check the error from Chrome. The encryption may be insecure and cause this error message.

Comment: I think [Jetty does not support TLS-PSK](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg07378.html) yet. You could try using stunnel as reverse proxy in front of Jetty to workaround this...